# How to ouput Unity as an NDI stream?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ndi

I want to use the rendered video of Unity and output it as an NDI stream instead of displaying it on the screen. I found online the KlakNDI plugin but I can't get it to work properly. Because I have no clue tho what Unity Game Object I should add the NDISender Script and how I get unity to disable the on screen output and output the video NDI only.

I tried to add the NDISender Script to the AR Session Origin Object and applied the settings Capture Method: Camera and used the AR Camera as input but that didn't work at all. I couldn't even access the NDI Stream from another device in my network.

Comment: Is this Keijiro's Klak? He can probably help: https://github.com/keijiro

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

if I got you correctly, you don't want to have the unity display your content (or the content you want to stream) on the screen. Right?
if that's the case then just keep in mind a way to control the application even if a small window

Aside from that, the NDI Sender component has the option to send/stream a texture. So you can use your camera to render to a Render Texture asset and stream it.